# In lattice homomorphism $f: L \to M$, does $f(a)\leq f(b)$ necessarily imply $a\leq b$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

In lattice homomorphism $f: L \to M$, does $f(a)\leq f(b)$ necessarily imply $a\leq b$?

if $a \leq b$ does not hold. Then $b\leq a$ (because $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ are comparable so $a$ and $b$ have to be comparable somehow ?)

$a\wedge b \leq a \vee b$ $\to$  $f(a\wedge b) \leq f(a \vee b)$ $\to  f(b) \leq f(a)$ contradiction.

Sorry I am new to discrete maths. Please help me

Comment: What if $f$ is a constant map?

Comment: Within a lattice, not a <= b doesn't always imply b <= a.

Comment: Why is $f(b)\le f(a)$ a contradiction? What does it contradict?